# Update doesnt work when part of long query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a long query that run without errors in pgadmin, with psql from the terminal etc.

The query ends with some updates:

```
update someschema.table1 t1
set
    area = round((area1 * (1-percentage/100::numeric))::numeric, 2),
    volume = round((area*(field1+field2::numeric)*0.82)::numeric, 0),
    volume_1 = round((volume * (someotherpercentage/100::numeric))::numeric, 0),
    and 4 more fields...;
```

But only the first field `area` is calculated when the whole query is executed, the  following fields are NULL. But when I rerun the update above manually (by selecting the section in pgadmin) all fields are calculated correctly.

What could be the reason for having to execute the last update manually for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *might be* a misconception about the way `update` works. Assignments are not processed *in order*: that is, all assignments see the values of the columns *before* the update.

Given, for example, this part of the query:

```
set
    area = round((area1 * (1-percentage/100::numeric))::numeric, 2),
    volume = round((area*(field1+field2::numeric)*0.82)::numeric, 0),
```

The first assignment sets `area`. But `area`  in the second assignment still refers to original value (its value at the time when the query was triggered), not the modified value. If that's what you intended, then you need to repeat the computation:

```
set
    area = round((area1 * (1-percentage/100::numeric))::numeric, 2),
    volume = round((
        round((area1 * (1-percentage/100::numeric))::numeric, 2) -- repeated computation
        *(field1+field2::numeric)*0.82
    )::numeric, 0),
```